# why can't I cat the file?

Tags: linux, find

I run:

```
find / -user alice -type f 2>>findlog.txt
```

to store search results within findlog.txt
but when I try to cat it, it outputs this:
[image]
any idea why I cant cat the file?

Comment: Please don't use images, copy the text and paste it into the answer. Why are you using `2>>findlog.txt`? The `2` refers to standard error, where errors are usually shown.

Comment: As what user are you trying to run `cat`? If it's a regular user and not `root`, then it's because you don't have access.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I see the reason, thanks for your help, it's readable now. it's because it didn't throw me any error... still don't know why it would tell me permission denied if it couldn't fetch any error messages though.

Comment: You *are* `cat`-ing the file, that's what the file contains.  You redirected standard error to the file, and those messages were printed to standard error.

Comment: @NasirRiley thank you, I created the file as the user that I'm trying to read the file on. I think the reason is that I'm trying to write error messages to a file where no error messages are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the command runs with no errors, then '2>>'
will not append anything to the file. Try either of:

```
find / -user alice -type f >>findlog.txt
find / -user alice -type f  >findlog.txt
```

depending on whether you want to append to,
or overwrite findlog.txt.  Or, try:

```
find / -user alice -type f  >findlog.txt 2>findlog.err
```

to save stdout and stderr separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cat` command works without problems. The issue is that when you ran your `find` command, it generated a number of "Permission denied" errors since you did not have access to all the directories that the `find` command wanted to examine.

Since you redirected the error stream from the `find` command with `2>>` to your `findlog.txt` file, you got these error messages appended to `findlog.txt` (while the ordinary output of `find` would most likely have ended up on your terminal).

If you instead want to save the non-error output of `find` to `findlog.txt`, use

```
find / -find f -user alice >findlog.txt
```

This would first truncate (empty) the output file before outputting the pathnames of all regular files in or under the `/` directory, owned by the user `alice`, to it.  Use `>>` to instead append to the file.

Would you want to throw away the error messages generated by this `find` command,
redirect the error stream to `/dev/null`:

```
find / -find f -user alice >findlog.txt 2>/dev/null
```